# Ways to keep user input data after session expiry on a webpage

Tags: javascript

Some pages remember input via Back/Forward. So you can copy your stuff. I imagine thats tricky.

I don't know any coding languages so as an outsider:

Isn't it easier to just trigger a login popup on top of whatever you are doing when your sessions has expired and you use an action that requires you be logged in?

I need to know if thats hard or the guy who's doing my webpage is bullshitting me for cash.

(obviously don't get into any pop-up blocking cases - assume popups are allowed.)

To clarify:

If we make a cookie that effectively re-logs you every time your session expires, we might as well make sessions never expire. The point is to - every now and then ask the user for credentials without wasting their current page input. Thats why I asked if instead of redirecting the user to login or disabling the page, can't we just trigger a login inside a new pop up? I haven't seen it done very often on the web thats why I asked if its complicated.

Comment: (I would not use this nor would I state u should do this) but could you not use a cookie system? Whereby login credentials are saved to the cookie if ur session expires use the credentials from the cookie for the session while the page has not been closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go about doing this. As far as coding ability personally I wouldn't say it's difficult enough to charge you an arm and a leg, but the complexity does depend on the language, the organization of the site, and along with those things, it's completely relative depending on who you've hired.

I guess to give you an example of storing information locally when a user visits a website using javascript you can do the following:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

for a more in depth look at that example you can check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I don't think so if that's what the user asked. He asked for some action to perform which keeps him logged in, if session expires.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your problem can be solved very easily with the use of `cookies` in you page. Setting cookie will let the user `logged in` for the specific time as specified by the programmer. 
If you are sure you just want some action to do if login session expired, then you need not to let the user perform some other action. Just store the relevant information in cookies instead of Session and user will be logged in.
Ask the person you hired for making the use of cookie.
For more details on how to work with and about cookies, visit [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)